# Exactly two neighbors

Tags: code-golf, self-validating

Given as input a list of positive integers, your task is to determine if every integer present has exactly two neighbors in the list. The neighbors of a integer \$x\$ are the distinct integers that appear next to an \$x\$ anywhere in the list.  For example in the list:

```
[1,3,4,4,3,2,1]
```

The number `3` has 3 neighbors `1`, `4` and `2`. So this input is not valid.  The list

```
[1,2,3,1]
```

is valid because every number has exactly two neighbors.

This is a [self-validating](/questions/tagged/self-validating) challenge, so in addition your code performing the task it must also be written so that when interpreted as a list of bytes, it passes the test itself. That is, every byte present in your source must have exactly two neighbors in your source.

You may take a list of positive integers for input in any reasonable method. Output one of two consistent distinct values. One value should only be output if the property is satisfied, the other if it is not.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

### Test cases

**truthy**

```
[]
[1,2,3,1]
[1,1,2,2]
```

**falsey**

```
[1]
[1,2]
[1,2,1,2]
[1,3,4,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: Is it required to handle the input of an empty list?

Comment: IMO the empty list could be either truthy or falsy.

Comment: @Yousername Yes, it is the first test case.

Comment: @Fatalize Could you elaborate? I don't see how it could be considered falsey.

Comment: @WheatWizard The convention to make it truthy makes sense. I was just saying that in terms of test cases, having it be either truthy or falsy (or a non-valid input) would avoid having to deal with this edge-case with boring extra code in answers

Comment: @Fatalize Under what logic could it be considered falsey?

Comment: @WheatWizard All elements of the empty list have 0 neighbors, not 2.

Comment: @Fatalize All members in the empty list have 0 neighbors *and* 2, and any number for that matter.

Comment: @WheatWizard And you chose 2 as convention which is fine, but it’s still a convention that is annoying to deal with for certain answers.

Comment: @Fatalize No, there's no choice by convention. I'm not saying that it's any particular count because it wouldn't make any sense. There's nothing in the list. When there exists none of something any statement quantified of that must be true.

Comment: @WheatWizard Well you could use the definition: The set of neighbour counts of all elments is {2}. Which is not too far-fetched and would leave out the empty list.

Comment: Consider [1, 2, 3, 1]. It's truthy, but there are an infinite number of potential members that have zero neighbors. They aren't considered a problem because they are absent. A universal quantifier over the empty set is [always true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#The_empty_set) and an existential quantifier over it is [always false](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification#The_empty_set). See, for another example, [Java's Stream.allMatch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223079/why-does-stream-allmatch-return-true-for-an-empty-stream).

Comment: @DavidConrad, What your referencing looks to be just a convention used by mathematicians to keep their proofs clean. Here in the practical world of actual programming, it's kind of nonsense to try and apply that.

Comment: @Fatalize The opposite of "every element of the list has 2 unique neighbors" is "some element of the list that doesn't have 2 unique neighbors". So for every falsy case, there must be an element of the list that witnesses that falsyness. The empty set has no such witness, and so it can't be falsy.

Comment: @ouflak It's not an arbitrary convention, but rather an unavoidable consequence of the meaning of "every". If a (poorly composed) Code Golf challenge said "write a program that matches every test case" but didn't include any test cases, then any program would be a valid answer, right?

Answer (score 20):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 2955 bytes

```python
eval("(lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalal("'[1 :37])mbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbm)]73: 1['"(lalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalalal("'[1 : : : : : : : : : : : : : : :37])mbdsdsdsdsds{u,inzp-+for*}<=2#eval("'"'[1 :3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:37])mbds{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{sdsdbm)]73: 1['"'"(lave#2=<}*rof+-pzni,u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{sdbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbmbm)]73: 1['"(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l("'[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1['"(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(lave#2=<}*rof+-pzni,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,i,i,i,i,inzp-+for*}<=2#eval("'[1 :37])m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)])])])])])]73: 1['"(lave#2=<}*rof+-pzninininininininininininininininininininznznznznznznznznzp-+for*}<=2#eval("'[1 : : : : : : : : : : : :37])mbds{u,inznzp-+for*}<=2#eval("'"'[1 :37])mbds{u,ininininininininininininininininininzpzpzpzpzpzpzpzpzpzni,u{sdbm)]73: 1['"'"(l(l(l(l(l(l(l(lave#2=<}*rof+-pzni,u{sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdbm)]73: 1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1 :3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3: 1['"(lave#2=<}*rof+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+for*}<=2#eval("'[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 :37]7]7]7]7]7]7]7]7]73: 1['"(lave#2=<}*rof+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-pzni,u{sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdbm)]73: 1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1 1['"'"(lave#2=<}*rof+-pzni,u{sdbm)]73:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:37])])])])])]73: 1['"(lave#2=<}*rof+-pzni,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u,u{sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdbm)]73: 1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1[1 1['"'"(lave#2=<}*rof+-pzni,u{sdbm)]73:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:3:37])])])])])])])])]73: 1['"(lave#2=<}*rof+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-pzni,u{s{s{s{s{u,inzp-+for*}<=2#eval("'[1 :37])])])])])])])])])]73: 1['"(lave#2=<}*rofofofofofofofofofofofofofofofofofofoforororororororororororororororororororororororororororof+-pzni,u{sdbm)]73: : : : : : : : : : : : : : :37])mbds{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{sdbm)]73: : : : : : : : : : : : : :37])mbds{u,inininininininininininininininininininznznznzp-+for*}<=2#eval("'[1 :37])mbds{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{sdbm)]73: 1['"(lave#2=<}*r*r*r*r*r*r*r*r*r*r*r*r*rof+-pzni,u{s{s{s{s{s{s{s{sdbm)]73: 1['"'"(lave#2=<}*}*}*}*}*}*}*}*}*}*rof+-pzni,u{sdbm)])])])])])])])])])])])])])])])])])])])m)m)m)m)m)m)m)m)]73: 1['"(lave#2=<}*rofofofofofofofofofofofofofofofofofofoforororororororororororororororororororororororororororof+-pzni,u{sdbm)]73: : : : 1['"'"(lave#2=<}*rof+-pzni,u{sdbmbmbmbmbds{u,inzp-+for*}<=2#eval("'"'[1 : : : : : : : : : : : : :37])mbds{u,inininininininininininininininininininininininininininzp-+for*}<=2#eval("'[1 : : : : : : : : : : : : : : :37])mbdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdbm)]73: 1['"(lave#2=<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<}<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<}*rof+-pzni,u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{u{sdbm)]73: 1['"'"(lave#2=2=2=2=2=2=2=2=2=2=2=2=2=2=2=2=2=2=<}*rof+-pzni,u{sdbm)]73: 1['[1 : :37])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=7ZfNboJAEMfvtg9B8CAoHoAmNkaexHKwRVISBYJiUohP0EfoxaRpH6pPU1cWXNmvsXow6fo7GBcZZv7M7sx8fKdv69ck3n2G3tNXvg6Hjz937_PNbGHoxmJ2IYbem9ra2B355vIZQnARS9MfuWPNnvZAvmPvRFSeB6uaMreiuEiHgzDJ-tuJ53QrqXo4UBHYVAli_zAynENAm3nX8SbbfpaEg2FaxJGVlzKQGRGkYgBQmABY1ljug4hqmMI3-QXCP0JkCuUZiKINxztxZlUZJcop8o8Ar1KKQ6LQ-SR_PeUq4HM0B4C1NZjqM2GoKgPJRnHOMzHXFgK5LtrPjTkAI2A2Q3bZ7UcojhPyDjG8I7zebMBngsj-BEMsSJGSFgKJpTNPmkhy7vEKXrtON5ryIPUQmDoxRkPLCoKqIDeUDdJ9VndVsr7lahlBV6NzaiK752IcQ2TQILwLEDdcvByUwzsXkaFKI6QE7snv7TSL4rURGlPfNDvND9tyLNeyW2to1UFr2uFDXGrfTBmj11zrYY-LrqErnZckmGuepuu6GhPUmKDGBDUmqDFBjQm3EqEaE9SYoMYENSb8szFh3413mqYddegmnhx2u-r7Fw)

D'oh!

#### How (if you can be bothered)

The long string slices down to

```
lambda s:{sum([(u,m)in zip(s[:-1]+s[1:],s[1:]+s)for u in{*s}])for m in s}<={2}
```

It was generated (by computer program) by walking up and down the string

```
[1 :37])mbds{u,inzp-+for*}<=2#eval(
```

wasting just the right amount of time to get the right characters at the chosen spacing.

#### A few more details:

Lets do a small example:

Let's assume our program is

```
abracadabra
```

The basic idea is arrange the unique letters in some order, UNQ = `abrcd`, say, and then do something like `ababrbrcdabrcrbadadadababrbrcda`. Because this was created by walking  up and down UNQ every letter has at most two neighbours. Now, if we slice this with  step = 3 we recover `abracadabra`:
`AbaBrbRcdAbrCrbAdaDadAbaBrbRcdA`. Note that in order to break parity we needed UNQ to be of odd length and to wrap around.

With the wrapping around all the spare neighbour slots we might have hoped to harness in the next step are used up. We'll see in a moment that that is a bit of a problem:

We still need to wrap our magic string in an `eval` statement and do the slicing.

But if we try something like `eval("ababrbrcdabrcrbadadadababrbrcda"[ : :3])` then the characters touching the quotation marks are over-booked. They already had two neighbours, so the quotation mark is one too many.

We can try and solve this by integrating the wrapper code into UNQ:
UNQ = `"[ :3])brcdeval(`

It almost works, but, of course, the single quotation mark will cause all sorts of problems when wrapping around. We could try a similar trick to the one we have already tacitly used to manage the double colon in the slicing expression: instead of `[::3]` (`:` has three neighbours) use `[ : :3]`. But with the colon we have used up the "neutral" space character already. We could try and use `tab` or even `newline` but there is one slightly neater way: use two kinds of quotes: single and double. UNQ = `"[ :3])brcdeval('` Then at every other wrap-around we have to add one wiggle over the quotes:
`"...'"'"....'".....'"'"....'` etc. Python will concatenate this into one single string that contains a few occurrences of the character pair `'"`.

Comment: This is really clever.  I had originally thought, "oh, the only submissions will be esos where you can write a program with all unique characters".  You proved me wrong.  I would be curious to see the generating prog.

Comment: @Jonah It's really ugly. You'd have to confirm first that I will not be held responsible for any permanent brain damage you may suffer from looking at it.

Comment: Perhaps a short summary of how the algo works instead?

Comment: @Jonah Haha! Did I manage to scare you off? I'll see what I can do for an explanation.

Comment: Do you have enough freedom in ordering the string `[1 :37])mbds{u,inzp-+for*}<=2#eval(` to golf the constant 37 down to a smaller number?

Comment: @Nitrodon I'd think that's very possible. Just be aware that it's the worst pair that sets the step size. So if, for example, there is a character with high neighbour count (<space> would be a candidate) it may be difficult to place all of them close (and with right distance parity) in the unique list.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ṢƝQ⁺€FċⱮ=2PṢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkXH5gY@atz1qGmN25HuRxvX2RoFAAX/H27XjPz/Pzo6Vocr2lDHSMdYxxDCBHGMwEyoFEwFnGmsYwKExiAhuG4gI78gNU9DXS85PyVVryQzX11Tryg1MSUnMy9VQ1OvuKQos0BDPSZPXTMWAA)

Inspired by [AndrovT's port of my original solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257530/85334), and come to think of it, basically ports [Kevin Cruijssen's solution from before porting that](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/257542/3). While Vyxal and 05AB1E have a nice single-byte palindromize builtin, Jelly's is a digraph, and flanking the program with `Œ` would effectively comment the whole thing out (though it is still nominally [accessible as a function](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7WnSOzQ10O9L9aOM6W5OAo5P@Gx7Zrxn5/390dKwOV7ShjpGOsY4hhAniGIGZUCmYCjjTWMcECI1BQnDdQEZ@QWqehrpecn5Kql5JZr66pl5RamJKTmZeqoamXnFJUWaBhnpMnrpmLAA), for the same byte count).

```
 Ɲ              For each pair of adjacent elements in the input,
Ṣ               yield it sorted.
  Q             Uniquify the list of pairs
   ⁺            then do it again
    €           to each pair.
       Ɱ  P     For every element of the input,
      ċ         is its number of occurrences in that list
     F          flattened
        =2      equal to 2?
           Ṣ    Sort the result (no-op).
```

My original solution, for posterity:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
¹ŒḄ,ƝQFċⱮ=4P¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QzqOTHu5o0Tk2N9DtSPejjetsTQIO7fx/uF0z8v//6OhYHa5oQx0jHWMdQwgTxDECM6FSMBVwprGOCRAag4TguoGM/ILUPA11veT8lFS9ksx8dU29otTElJzMvFQNTb3ikqLMAg31mDx1zVgA)

*-1 porting AndrovT's Vyxal answer back*

```
 ŒḄ              Palindromize the input, making all adjacencies bidirectional.
   ,ƝQ           Find the unique pairs of adjacent elements.
        Ɱ  P     For every element of the input,
       ċ         is its number of occurrences in that list
      F          flattened
         =4      equal to 4?
¹           ¹    No-ops.
```

Comment: @Jonah "Note the trailing space." I guess I could use a different no-op for visual clarity though!

Answer (score 9):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>20</s> 11 bytes

```
∞2lUfvO4=A∞
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oieMmxVZnZPND1B4oieIiwiIiwiW11cblsxLDIsNCwxXVxuWzEsMSwyLDJdXG5bMV1cblsxLDJdXG5bMSwyLDEsMl1cblsxLDMsNCw0LDMsMiwxXSJd)

This is valid because all characters except `∞` are used exactly once and `∞` is both at the beginning and the end.

Now uses the same approach as @Unrelated String's Jelly answer.

```
∞2lUfvO4=A∞
∞            # palindromize
 2l          # overlapping pairs
   U         # uniquify
    f        # flatten
     vO      # for each in number input count how many times it occurs
       4=    # is equal to four?
         A   # are all true?
          ∞  # palindromize
```

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ûü2Ù˜s¢4QPû
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@CommandMaster*.
-1 byte porting [*AndrovT*'s Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257530/52210), which is based on [*@UnrelatedString*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257534/52210), so make sure to upvote both of them as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8O7De4wOzzw9p/jQIpPAgMO7//@PNtQx1jEBQmMdIx3DWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8O7D@8xOjzz9JziQ4tMAgMO7/6v8z86OlYn2lDHSMdYxxDMArGNYnUUoiFcI6g0jGWsYwKExiCR2FgA) or [verify its own source](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9vc2FiaWX/Iv/Du8O8MsOZy5xzwqI0UVDDu/8iwrZLw5A/IiDihpIgIj/FvsSGc1Nrcy5WP/8).

**Explanation:**

```python
û           # Palindromize the (implicit) input-list
 ü2         # Get all overlapping pairs of this list
   Ù        # Uniquify the pairs
    ˜       # Flatten it
     s      # Swap the (implicit) input-list to the top of the stack†
      ¢     # Count how many times each value of the input occurs in the list
       4Q   # Check for each count whether it's equal to 4 (1 if 4; 0 otherwise)
         P  # Get the product to check if all are truthy
          û # No-op palindromize (1 or 0 will remain as is)
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

† Could be just `I` (push input), but with a swap it's easier to write the source verifier.

Comment: The code in [verify its own source](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf9vc2FiaWX/Iv93w7wy4oKsw6rDmcucRMKiPEln4omgwqpQd/8iwrZLRD8iIOKGkiAiP8W@xIZzU2tYLlY//w) seems to ignore the actual input and just output `1`. [This](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP9vc2FiaWX/Iv93w7wy4oKsw6rDmcucRMKiPEln4omgwqpQd/8iwrZLw5A/IiDihpIgIj/FvsSGc1Nrcy5WP/8 "05AB1E – Try It Online") should work, I believe

Comment: Additionally, I don't see why [`wü2€êÙ˜I¢<Pw`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@//PAeo0dNaw6vOjzz9BzPQ4tsAsr//482NLTUUTAyNdJRMDXQUTA0sgDyjE2AhKE5kAsSNzcGMsyADDOgAguQIkPLWAA) can't work for 12 bytes.

Comment: @CommandMaster Ah, I accidentally left the `X` in the verifier after I removed the `U` and used a Duplicate instead. And thanks for the -4 to combine the check and edge case!

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
s₂ᶠ{|↔ᵐ}ᵇcdhᵍlᵛ2∨?Ės
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/hRU9PDbQuqax61TXm4dULtw63tySkZD7f25jzcOtvoUccK@yPTiv//jzbUMdYxAUJjHSMdw9j/UQA)

This code is self-validating because all symbols are used only once, except `s` used at the very beginning and very end.

3 bytes lost to deal with the empty list.

#### Explanation

```
s₂ᶠ                    Find all sublists of 2 consecutive elements
   {|↔ᵐ}ᵇc             Append the list of reversed sublists to it
          d            Remove duplicate sublists
           hᵍ          Group by the first element of each sublist
             lᵛ2       Verify that each group has length 2
                ∨?Ė    Else: the input is the empty list
                   s   Sublist of the empty list, always succeeds (only here for self-validation constraint)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 18 bytes

```
IΠmo=4`#ΣuẊe§+h↔¹I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8b/nuQW5@bYmCcrnFpc@3NWVemi5dsajtimHdnr@//8/WklJR8nQyNgQRBkaGYEosIghmGlsYmJsBBLAbYhSLAA)

Outputs `1` if every integer present has exactly two neighbors, `0` otherwise.
Could be [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8b/nudm2JrkJyucWlz7c1ZV6aLl2xqO2KYd2ev7//z9aSUlHydDI2BBEGRoZgSiwiCGYaWxiYmwEEsBphlIsAA) with output as truthy (nonzero) or falsy (zero).

```
                 I  # identity = leave input unchanged
I                   # identity = leave output unchanged
 Π                  # get the product of
  m                 # mapping over the input:
   o                #   composition of 2 functions:
      `#            #     number of instances
    =4              #     equals 4          
        Σ           # among all elements from
         u          # unique 
          Ẋe        # adjacent pairs
            +       # in the concatenation of
             h      # the head (omit last item)
              ↔     # and the reverse
               ¹    # of the input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 24 bytes

```
!!smn2l{fPI<1T.-R]dC,tQQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HUw9D0AwEP0rtZe01dZJbCYbYpNuIgZEoov48fXO8N7d@7i7nrillGX3cZr9Xfuu0VORj2FpZRyGlOaylIKhtQOpmjclhVOsCGQ4VEYKglVBeEyLHllMD@CQkNd/EaGvYFp@hJQ0I3w)

Outputs False for truthy and True for falsy. Self validating since each character is used only once except the start and end which are repeated once.

#### Explanation

```
!!smn2l{fPI<1T.-R]dC,tQQQ    # implicitly add Q
                             # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
   m                    Q    # map Q over lambda d
                   C,tQQ     #   take all pairs of adjacent elements in Q
              .-R]d          #   remove d from each pair once if possible
        f                    #   filter for pairs that are no longer pairs by looking at
         PI<1T               #     T[:-1] == T[:-1][:-1]
       {                     #   deduplicate
    n2l                      #   number of remaining elements != 2
  s                          # sum (if any elements did not have two neighbors the sum will be non zero)
!!                           # not not (takes 0 to False and non zero to True)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 13 bytes (26 nibbles)

```
|$!=2,|`$.!>>@_:`<$?$@ ~39
```

This corresponds to the [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) program with bytes:

```
93 c0 1a d9 ec 9c 04 51 e3 d4 f3 40 93
```

Output is falsy (empty) if all elements have exactly 2 neighbours, truthy (nonempty list of elements that do not have exactly 2 neighbours) otherwise.

```
|$!=2,|`$.!>>@_:`<$?$@  # main program:
|                       # filter
 $                      # the input
                        # keeping elements for which
     ,|                 #   the number of
       `$.!>>@_:`<$     #   of all adjacent pairs
                   ?$@  #   that contain them
  !=2                   #   is not equal to 2
  
       `$.!>>@_:`<$     # adjacent pairs:
       `$               # get unique elements of
         .              #   map over
          !>>@_:        #   all adjacent pairs
                `<$     #      sorting them
                
~39                     # finally append nibbles 0 9 3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, <s>202</s> 199 bytes

```js
a=>{let o=1;a.forEach(i=>{let n=[];a.forEach((j,y)=>{if(j==i){if(y!=0)if(!n.includes(a[y-1]))n.push(a[y-1]);if(y!=a.length-1)if(!n.includes(a[y+1]))n.push(a[y+1])}});if(n.length!=2){o=0;}});return o}
```

Gets an array as input and return `1` for true and `0` for false

Ungolfed version:

```js
let x = a => {
  let o = 1;
  a.forEach((i) => {
    let n = [];
    a.forEach((j, y) => {
      if (j == i) {
        if (y != 0) if (!n.includes(a[y - 1])) n.push(a[y - 1]);
        if (y != a.length - 1) if (!n.includes(a[y + 1])) n.push(a[y + 1]);
      }
    });
    if (n.length != 2) {
      o = 0;
    }
  });
  return o;
};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxNCoMwEIX3PYXuEqrB2KVMdz2FuAgxaiRMJGpRxLNbYy200NW8n/leK56il053Q4y2VJtRQzDBJuC@eGmBZ4JV1j2EbIg@U4S8@IpJG810r3RFWgBNvZhDSOh@Q2QapRlL1RORzzEvKEXWjX3zsdn7WzCjsB6amP/Brr@Yt@t6kHhiIaR0sZBkPndqGB0Gdt2kxd4axYytyURyHqXRLfJjlz9NejTbCw)

Comment: I think you missed the additional [tag:self-validating] restriction: "... it must also be written so that when interpreted as a list of bytes, it passes the test itself. That is, every byte present in your source must have exactly two neighbors in your source." With a quick look I can see a has at least 4 neighbors.

Comment: @WheatWizard Oops, yeah I didnt understand that. It is really hard to do it in languages like js, c, c++, ...

Comment: I Dont have any idea of how doing this...

Comment: The [python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257546/56656) should give an idea for how this could be done in JS.